# Unclear how to implement operator overloading in a class derived from an abstract base class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class

Our professor was very unclear about this so I hope I'm not too vague about this. Basically we need to write an abstract base class from which other (non abstract) classes inherit, the header file of the abstract base class looks like this:

```
//AbstractBase.h 
class AbstractBase
{
    public:
        AbstractBase();
        virtual int operator+ (int)=0;
}
```

I have no idea what to put in the implementation .cpp file since it's an abstract class (so you can't create any objects from that class, I'm probably very very wrong here) so I just didn't make one.

Then there's the derived class with a header file and implementation as follows:

```
//Headerfile for DerivedClass
#include "AbstractBase.h"
class DerivedClass: public AbstractBase
{
    public:
        DerivedClass(double &);
        DerivedClass * operator+ (DerivedClass*);
        double getVar();
        void setVar(double)
    private:
        double Var;
}

//Implementation of DerivedClass
#include "DerivedClass.h"
class DerivedClass::DerivedClass(double &Input) :Var(Input)
{}

double DerivedClass::getVar()
{
    return Var;
}

void DerivedClass::setVar(double Input)
{
    Var=Input;
}

DerivedClass * DerivedClass::operator+ (DerivedClass * object)
{
    double Sum;
    Sum=Var+object->getVar()
    DerivedClass result(Sum);
    return result;
}
```

So my question comes down to this:

- the overloading part (last lines) should do the following: when I add
  two object of the class DerivedClass, it should just add the private
  variables (double Var) together. I've done some searching but
  couldn't immediately find something that I could use (perhaps because
  of my limited knowledge on this matter).

A small side question:

- what do I do with the AbstractBase class? My task description states
  that it should only contain 4 virtual functions that are all
  overloading an operator. But it's an abstract base class and I don't
  know yet HOW I would overload them (i.e. it's like saying "add two
  things, I have no idea how but I know you can add em up...", that's
  all the abstract class says)

Edit: some clarification on how I think it should happen.

The abstract base class contains a virtual function operator+. In the derived class, I define a new operator+ which knows how to handle the addition of objects of the derived class. If I use a pointer of the type DerivedClass* it will ignore the virtual function and go for the operator+ function defined in the DerivedClass (the basic principle of virtual functions?). The problem seems that the derived class is still seen as an abstract class, so I can't use the code provided by Component 10, because that instantiates an object of DerivedClass (which isn't possible because apparently it's abstract)

Edit 2:

Our professor decided to leave out the operator overloading because it involved too complex code :D Thanks for the help anyway, I did learn how to correctly implement it (sort of).

Comment: Your professor wants you to override this **virtual int operator+ (int)=0;**, not write your own operator+. I maybe wrong also. I believe that is the whole point of inheriting from an abstract base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit confusing. Assuming your base class is correct, you'll need a constructor since you've declared one:

```
AbstractBase::AbstractBase() {}
```

You don't need to implement the operator+ here. I'm not sure what you're getting at with your derived `operator+` but it should probably look as follows:

```
DerivedClass DerivedClass::operator+ (const DerivedClass& rhs)
{
    return DerivedClass(Var + rhs.Var);
}
```

That will not override your base `operator+ (int)` though.

Is the purpose of this to demonstrate virtual functions or operator overloading? Either way, I think you need some clarity from your professor on what they are looking for.

Comment: The purpose is to calculate the chaotic behaviour of a coupled double pendulum :D So I need to write an abstract class ODEProblem that has 4 overloaded operators and an inheriting class Pendulum where you are able to add objects of the pendulum class in such a way that it comes down to producing a new object which has private data members which are the sum of the original 2 objects (so a sort of fancy vector).

Comment: Also what about the return type? I get the error "function returning abstract class DerivedClass is not allowed" if I use that.

Comment: @PatronBernard: That's because in returning it's trying to instantiate an object of type `DerivedClass` and the compiler thinks that `DerivedClass` is abstract. At a guess, I'd say that it's because you haven't implemented the `virtual int operator+ (int)=0;` pure virtual function declared in your base class in 'DervicedClass'. Unless you implement all the base class pure virtuals in your derived classes, you won't be able to instantiate it and all you can do is derive from it.